# Qt C++: Connect call fails in header in dynamic library

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following code which fails to connect for signals in header file for dynamic library(TestTemplateInheritance) but does work fine for static library

//TestTemplateInheritance.pro

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = $$qtLibraryTarget($$TARGET)
TEMPLATE = lib
SOURCES += \
    base.cpp \  

HEADERS += \
    base.h \
```

//base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
class Q_DECL_EXPORT Base : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Base(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void testSignal();
  public:
    template <class T>
    void callInHeader(T arg)
    {
        qCritical()<<"Does it connect here? in " << arg;
        connect(this, &Base::testSignal, this, &Base::testSlot);
    }
    void callInDefinition();
public slots:
    void testSlot()
    {
        qCritical() << "Slot called";
    }
};
#endif // BASE_H
```

//base.cpp

```
#include "base.h"

Base::Base(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{    
}
void Base:: callInDefinition()
{
    qCritical()<<"Does it connect here?";
    connect(this, &Base::testSignal, this, &Base::testSlot);
    qCritical()<<"Yes it does!";
}
```

Now the application

//TestTemplateFail.pro

```
QT       += core
QT       -= gui
TARGET = TestTemplateFail
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../release/release -lTestTemplateInheritance
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

//main.cpp

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "../TestTemplateInheritance/base.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QObject *obj = new QObject();
    Base* d = new Base(obj);
    d->callInHeader<QString>("header");
    d->callInDefinition();
    return a.exec();
}
```

RESULT:

```
Does it connect here? in  "header"
QObject::connect: signal not found in Base
Does it connect here?
Yes it does!
```

If I build a static library(CONFIG += staticlib) instead of a dynamic library. There is no connect error

RESULT:

```
Does it connect here? in  "header"
Does it connect here?
Yes it does!
```

I also observed that its not just function template, the connect statement in any function which is defined in the header file fails. Function templates are more obvious ones to have definition in header file.  So why does the connect statement fail in the functions defined in the header file in dynamic library fail?

Comment: It does work using Qt 5.8 with both MSVC2015 and MinGW. Which Qt version and OS are you using?

Comment: Desktop Qt 5.4.2 MinGW 32bit on Windows

Comment: I also just tested now with Qt 5.7 MinGW 32 bit leads to same results as mentioned in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with this line:

```
class Q_DECL_EXPORT Base : public QObject
```

When the header is included from another program (as opposed to when you compile your library) it should be :

```
class Q_DECL_IMPORT Base : public QObject
```

The easy solution is to replace it by:

```
#if defined(MYLIB_LIBRARY)
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
class MYLIBSHARED_EXPORT Base : public QObject
```

and add

```
DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY
```

ONLY in the .pro file of your library.

Comment: Thanks It did work after changing to the below code 
class MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT Base : public QObject

  public:
    template <class T>
    MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT void callInHeader(T arg);

Comment: `MYSHAREDLIB_EXPORT` for the inline function is not required for me. In fact it prevents me from linking the final binary (`error: function '...' definition is marked dllimport`)